# Why are my D3 axis labels squished?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am attempting to create a d3 scatterplot with ordinal categories on the y axis. My problem is that the letters representing the ordinal categories appear to be superimposed on one another. I would like them to appear as complete words.

I increased the value of `margin.left` from 100 to 300 in the hopes this would widen the space between the graph and the left edge of the svg container. This moved both the graph and margin by 300 and as the image shows, the margin remains narrow.

[image]

Other things I've tried:

- adding .tickFormat(function(d,i){ return name[i] }) to the last line
- removing other instances of 'margin.left' in the code.

```js
var data = [
  [50, 30],
  [100, 170],
  [15, 40],
  [20, 80]
];
var name = ["maggie", "milly", "molly", "may"];
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 150,
    bottom: 60,
    left: 100
  },
  width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d[0];
  })])
  .range([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d[0];
  })])

var y = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .domain(name)
  .range([30, 170, 40, 80]);

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y);
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x);


var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.selectAll("circle")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return d[0];
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return d[1];
  })
  .attr("r", 5);

var chartGroup = svg.append("g");


chartGroup.append("g").attr("class", "x axis").attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")").call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(5));
chartGroup.append("g").attr("class", "y axis hidden").call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(5));
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an interesting and unusual problem. The issue here is just your unfortunate choice of name (no pun intended), namely `name`.

Despite not being a reserved word, strange things may happen when you use `name`. Have a look at this snippet:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var name = ["alice", "bernard", "chris"];
var scale = d3.scalePoint()
  .domain(name)
  .range([20, 280]);
var axis = d3.axisBottom(scale)(svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,50)"));
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

That reproduces your issue.

Now let's simply call `name` something else, like `anotherName`:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var anotherName = ["alice", "bernard", "chris"];
var scale = d3.scalePoint()
  .domain(anotherName)
  .range([20, 280]);
var axis = d3.axisBottom(scale)(svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,50)"));
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

If you want to research more about [this issue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name), this may give you a hint:

```js
console.log(name)
```

Hint: I never defined `name` in the snippet above.

Comment: I changed the variable 'name' and the names appeared on the axis!  So happy.  Thank you.  PS. nice pun.